# Ошибка в методе, который находит в тексте наименьшие и наибольшие слова

Tags: c#

Программа исправно ищет наибольшее и наименьшее слово, но когда я решил добавить поиск всех больших слов (т.е. если слово = по длине наибольшему, то оно тоже выписывается), заметил, что программа делает больше циклов, чем вводится слов в массив. В чем моя ошибка? Я просто не понимаю, почему цикл работает больше раз, чем кол-во слов, которое я ввожу

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string minWord = "";
        string maxWord = "";
        int min = 999999;
        int max = 0;
        string text = Console.ReadLine();
        text = text.Trim();
        Console.WriteLine($"Min word: {GetWord(text).Item1}\nMax word: {GetWord(text).Item2}");
        Console.ReadKey();

        (string, string) GetWord(string word)
        {
            string[] Arr = word.Split(' ', ',', '.');
            for (int i = 0; i < Arr.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Arr[i].Length < min)
                {
                    min = Arr[i].Length;
                    minWord = Convert.ToString(Arr[i]);
                }
                else if (Arr[i].Length == max)
                {
                    maxWord = maxWord + " " + Arr[i];
                }
                else if (Arr[i].Length > max)
                {
                    max = Arr[i].Length;
                    maxWord = Convert.ToString(Arr[i]);
                }

            }
            return (minWord, maxWord);
        }
```

Comment: А как вы заметили число циклов - проходили отладчиком или что? Печати у вас никакой нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, что за "лишние итерации" вы принимаете второй вызов `GetText`:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Min word: {GetWord(text).Item1}\nMax word: {GetWord(text).Item2}");
```

В результате для максимального слова вы получаете удвоенную строку - ведь строка `maxWord` находится за пределами функции `GetText`...

Перенесите переменные в `GetText`, и все получится:

```
(string, string) GetWord(string word)
{
    string minWord = "";
    string maxWord = "";
    int min = 999999;
    int max = 0;
    string[] Arr = word.Split(' ', ',', '.');
    for (int i = 0; i < Arr.Length; i++)
    ...
```

Пусть и неэффективно. Но лучше бы второго вызова `GetText` и вовсе избежать:

```
        var (m, M) = GetWord(text);
        Console.WriteLine($"Min word: {m}\nMax word: {M}");
```

**Update**

К комментарию об инициализации минимального/максимального значений — можно сделать так:

```
(string, string) GetWord(string word)
{
    string[] Arr = word.Split(' ', ',', '.');
    string minWord = Arr[0], maxWord = Arr[0];
    int min = Arr[0].Length;
    int max = Arr[0].Length;

    for (int i = 1; i < Arr.Length; i++)
    {
         ....
```

Comment: Да, дьявол крылся в деталях. И второй вызов был вообще не уместен - все ломал, особенно когда слов становилось слишком много)

Comment: `999999` => `int.MaxValue`

Answer (score 0):

Вы написали какой-то велосипед.

Советую использовать более легкий и, главное, понятный способ.

В коде ниже используеться LINQ метод [Order By](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=net-6.0):

```
(string, string) GetWord(string word)
{
    var arr = word.Split(' ', ',', '.');
    var orderedArr = arr.OrderBy(w => w.Length).ToList();
    return (orderedArr.First(), orderedArr.Last());
}
```

Comment: я бы добавил "использовать более легкий и, главное, понятный способ, но чтобы он стал понятным - Вам нужно разобраться в LINQ"

Comment: @S.H. исправил.

Comment: Спасибо, очень полезно! Я просто еще не дошел до списков, теперь обязательно изучу.

Comment: Осталось переделать под "*поиск **всех** больших слов*".

Comment: Кстати, специалисты в C#, подскажите — тут же будет по сути сортировка, получается, O(N lg N), в то время как у автора O(N)?

Comment: @Harry да, но до .NET 5 выполнялось за O(N). [Доказательства](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/orderby-firstordefault-complexity-increase#change-description) (но не всё так гладко)

Comment: @Aarnihauta Но даже до .NET 5 не сработало бы — потому что тут за `OrderBy` не следует `First`, а следует `ToList`.

Comment: @Harry по идее код можно изменить